# Update a column value and move the undesired values to another column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a column called NAME and another column called NOTES. The NAME column will have values such as 202.2(WCCP-P1 6)202.2 but the NAME column should only have numbers with a decimal. for instance, what should only stay at NAME must be 202.2 and the remaining text (WCCP-P1 6) should be moved to NOTES column.

The NOTES column, can have some values or be empty before the query runs. If there is value, it should concat what was trimmed from the NAME column.

This is the code I have tried so far but with no luck. The NAME column stills stays with all the text.

My DB is in postgreSQL

```
export async function up({ context: queryInterface }: MigrationInterface) {
  await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
    UPDATE nodes
    SET notes = CONCAT(notes, ' ', REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[0-9.]+', '')),
        name = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9.]', '')
    WHERE name <> '';
  `);
}

/** Reverts the changes made in the up function */
export async function down({ context: queryInterface }: MigrationInterface) {
  await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
    UPDATE nodes
    SET name = CONCAT(name, ' ', notes),
        notes = ''
    WHERE notes <> '';
  `);
}
```

Comment: are the 200.2 always doubled in the text? or could there also be 202.2(WCCP-P1 6)202.3

Comment: You don't want to do a replace for the notes portion. You want to grab the matching text.

Comment: Not always doubled but if it appears in the name column, it will be the same number. Not different, for instance: 20.3(WCCP-P1 6)20.3 or 101.4(WCCP-P1 6)101.4 or just 20.3(WCCP-P1 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have *well formatted input strings* there are 2 approaches to take here: 1. Extracting the desired values using only normal string functions. 2. Extracting the desired values using regular expressions. Each follows:

```
-- 1. Extracting with only regular string handling functions  
with snode(ctid, beg_pos, end_pos) as 
     (select ctid, position('(' in name), position(')' in name)
        from nodes_sf
       where name is not null
     )  --select *,substring(name,1,beg_pos-1) from snode;
update nodes_sf n
   set name  = substring(name,1,beg_pos-1)                                    -- extract upto (
     , notes = concat(substring(name,beg_pos,end_pos-beg_pos+1), ' ', notes)  -- extract (...) 
  from snode
 where n.ctid= snode.ctid
   and beg_pos>1;
 
   
   
-- 2. Extracting with regualr_expresion:  
with snode(ctid, name, notes) as 
     (select ctid
           , regexp_replace(name, '^(.*)(\(.*\)).*$', '\1')  -- extract upto (
           , regexp_replace(name, '^(.*)(\(.*\)).*$', '\2')  -- extract (...) 
        from nodes_rx
       where name ~ '\d\('
     )  --select * from snode;
update nodes_rx n
   set notes = concat(snode.notes, ' ', n.notes) 
     , name  = snode.name 
  from snode
 where n.ctid= snode.ctid;
```

The CTE in the string functions only identifies the [position()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-position/) within the string of the delimiters **(...)**. These are then used with [substring()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-substring/) function to extract the actual values. The CTE in the regular expression method directly extracts the desired values. You did not specify the order of concatenating where `notes` already contains a value. Your description implied the sequence *extracted value then existing value*, this is the order used.  

Now lets look at restoring the initial data. Well actually your `down` function is on the correct path. However, there are 3  scenarios
it does not handle, 1 of which results in *loss of data*, 1 of which results in either `loss of data` or `additional data`, and 1 which may not be desired but cannot be avoided.

1. Any preexisting value in the `notes` column is lost.
2. You cannot in all cases restore the initial formats like
   `101.4(WCCP-P1 6)101.4` and also `20.3(WCCP-P1 6)`. There is nothing
   telling the process to use or not use the second occurrence.
   You must choose one format; either all have the numeric value both before and after or none have the numeric value after
   (well I guess you could choose to have it only after).
3. Any rows which had previously been processed will also be restored.
   This is currently an all-or-nothing process.

The following *corrects* #1 above. Correction for either of the other requires redesign (additional columns).

```
-- Restore Name and Notes  
with snode(ctid, beg_pos, end_pos) as 
     (select ctid, position('(' in  notes), position(')' in notes)
        from nodes_sf
       where name is not null
     )  -- select * from snode;
update nodes_sf n
   set name  = concat(n.name, substring( n.notes,1,end_pos))                                   
     , notes = substring(n.notes,end_pos+2) 
  from snode
 where n.ctid= snode.ctid
   and beg_pos=1;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bIONDZI_). It contains implementations in raw sql. You will need to translate to your obscurification language. if necessary. Further, it only includes the string function version of restore, I leave the regular expression version for you.